# Can a patch be made/installed during Spring '16 blackout?

Tags: managed-package, patch, spring16

The Dev org for our Managed Package Spring '16 upgrade is scheduled to be done tomorrow (Feb 6). We have an Extension Package org and several customer orgs related that are not going to be upgraded until Feb 13th.

From what I understand during that time period we will not be able to install major releases for our customer (or into the extension org) because it will be a Spring '16 release attempting to be installed on a Winter '16 org.

Does the same apply for patches? If the customer finds a critical defect during the blackout period am I also disallowed from patching anything from our package dev org to them?

Any insight you could provide would be greatly appreciated

AngiB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question to the Salesforce Partner Community 'Technical Enablement' Group on the same day...

Very soon after Andrew Albert (Salesforce) wrote...

The act of the packaging org getting upgraded to the Spring16 release alone won't impact you ability to upgrade/patch your customers.

If you upload a new package version (and/or a new patch version) of the managed package AFTER the respective DE "packaging" orgs are upgraded to Spring16, then you can only install/upgrade those new package versions to Spring'16 upgraded orgs.

If you don't upgrade/upload a new package version, you can continue to install/upgrade/patch any customer (if they have or have not been upgraded to Spring16).